How to set a Task to repeat?
I'm using the Google Tasks API via Google Apps Script and I'm trying to create a task that repeats on a schedule. I can, of course, set a repeating task manually via tasks.google.com.
I can create a task with Tasks.newTask(), but there's no "repeat" property or anything like that mentioned in the API documentation. When I create a repeating task manually, it has these properties:
{
    position=00000000000000000000,
    notes=these are the details,
    title=my task,
    etag="MNAzETkpNDQ3Nw",
    selfLink=https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/lists/S0p4TFEJX3BvOHFuPkpxRQ/tasks/ZG9xNHA3vXRGcnV2RUgwMw,
    links=[],
    webViewLink=https://tasks.google.com/task/doq304ioSrbvEH03,
    id=ZG9xNHA3vXRGcnV2RUgwMw,
    status=needsAction,
    updated=2024-08-10T18:16:30.000Z,
    due=2024-08-31T00:00:00.000Z,
    kind=tasks#task
}

The repeat periodicity isn't included in the object, and no apparent way to get or set it.
Is it possible to set a task to repeat via the API? If so, how would I do it?
